# How do I create a model and view based on a SQL Server stored procedure that returns a pivot table?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc, visual-studio-2019

I have a very complex stored procedure that returns a pivot table of data. This data is dynamic. Column names will change and the number of columns can change. Based of the number of chart audits that were audited for a particular physician. This is how SQL Server returns the data from the stored procedure for a particular physician.

```
Question                A    B      C    D     Average
--------------------------------------------------------
11_ChartWellOrg         5.0  6.0    6.0  6.0    5.8
12_HistInfoAdequate     5.0  6.0    5.0  5.0    5.3
14_PhysExamAdequate     6.0  6.0    6.0  6.0    6.0
16_AssessFormulation    6.0  6.0    5.0  6.0    5.8
18_PlanTreatAdequate    6.0  6.0    6.0  6.0    6.0
20_GlobalOverallAssess  6.0  6.0    6.0  6.0    6.0
```

In the past, I simply put this in a DataGrid that I could handle the dynamic portion with code behind the page.

```
Public Sub BindGridView()
    Dim tc As New TestCode
    Dim dt As New DataTable

    If intType <> 3 Then
        dt = tc.GetDT(intParticipant, intActivity, intAuditor, dBatch)
    Else
        dt = tc.GetDT(intParticipant, intActivity, intAuditor, intMonth, intYrChartEntry, intDept)
    End If
    intRows = dt.Rows.Count
    intColumns = dt.Columns.Count

    gvPivot.DataSource = dt
    gvPivot.DataBind()
    gvPivot.HeaderRow.Visible = True
    gvPivot.HeaderRow.BackColor = Drawing.Color.FromArgb(79, 113, 185)
    GridFormat()

End Sub
```

The requirement now is that I move this to a web portal we have built using ASP.NET Core 3.1 MVC. I figured I could load this into a DataTable and send it to this view:

```
@using System.Data
@model DataTable

@{
}
<div>
    <div>
        <h4>Matrix</h4>
        <table id="tblData" class="table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    @foreach(DataColumn col in Model.Columns)
                    {
                        <th>@col.ColumnName</th>
                    }
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @foreach (DataRow row in Model.Rows)
                {
                    <tr>
                        @foreach (DataColumn col in Model.Columns)
                        {
                            <td>@row[col.ColumnName]</td>
                        }
                    </tr>
                }
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

I figured that would handle the dynamic part of the DataTable that was supplied.

What I cannot figure out is how to get the data using my DBContext. I do not think this can handle dynamic tables or models. Can I go around the DBContext and pull this data outside of the DBContext? Is that bad form? I am novice to MVC and Entity Framework. I have done well so far with the portal, this one is just beating me about the head and neck. Suggestions? Help? Drugs?

If I need to supply more information, let me know. I usually do not post on forums because the answers already seem to be there and I do not have to ask the question.

Comment: Just don't try to do this with EF. Use Dapper, the perfect tool to get dynamic data.

Comment: So I am very new to the MVC and EF game.  "Use Dapper" really does not help me.  I am looking at dapper and I am not sure how it can help me.  Can I use it and EF in unison with Dapper?  The entire portal is built using EF Core.  Will everything need to be rewritten, or can I pull this one data set with Dapper while using EF core for the rest of the project?

Comment: It's still a data table returned from a stored proc, right? If so, you don't HAVE to use EF class mappings for it. This is an example that might be more complex than you need, but to give you an idea https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5263745/Return-DataTable-Using-Entity-Framework

Comment: One more example https://gunnarpeipman.com/aspnet-core-reporting-dataset-datatable/

Comment: OK, so you guys are kinda awesome.  I will admit it.  These look like the things that will help me.  I will put my fingers and mind to it and see what I can get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the answer was pretty simple and I was overthinking it.  Getting the data into a DataTable, and then letting the View handle the dynamic part was all that was necessary.  This is how I got the dynamic Stored Procedure data:

```
var dt = new DataTable();

using (var command = context.Database.GetDbConnection().CreateCommand())
{
    command.CommandText = "YourStoredProcedureName";
    command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue(...);
    
if (command.Connection.State != ConnectionState.Open)
{
    command.Connection.Open();
}

using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
{
    dt.Load(reader);
}
}
```

I used the Controller to get this in to the correct model:

```
[Route("[Controller]/[Action]/{IDParticipant_2}/{IDActivity}/{IDAuditor_5}/{BatchDate}")]
public async Task<ActionResult> ChartAuditMatrix(int IDParticipant_2, int IDActivity, int IDAuditor_5, DateTime BatchDate)
{
    DataTable table = await _chartAuditRepo.GetMatrix(IDParticipant_2, IDActivity, IDAuditor_5, BatchDate);
    var overallAssess = await _chartAuditRepo.GetOverallAssessmentNote(IDParticipant_2, IDActivity, IDAuditor_5, BatchDate);
    ViewBag.BatchDate = BatchDate;

    var model = new MatrixVM
    {
        Matrix = table,
        AllAuditAssessment = overallAssess
    };

    return View(model);
}
```

Here is the model that has two properties one being the DataTable that houses the pivot table from above:

```
public class MatrixVM
{
    public DataTable Matrix { get; set; }
    public AllAuditAssessment AllAuditAssessment { get; set; }
}
```

Then I used the Model as the basis for the View that handled the dynamic portion of the DataTable result:

```
@using System.Data
@model MatrixVM

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3 offset-1">
        <table id="tblMatrix" class="table" style="border: solid; background-color: white;">
            <thead style="background-color: darkgray;">
                <tr>
                    @foreach (DataColumn col in Model.Matrix.Columns)
                    {
                        @if (col.ColumnName == "ZZ_Average")
                        {

                            <th>Average</th>
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            <th>@col.ColumnName</th>
                        }

                    }
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @foreach (DataRow row in Model.Matrix.Rows)
                {
                    <tr>
                        @foreach (DataColumn col in Model.Matrix.Columns)
                        {
                            <td>
                                @row[col.ColumnName]
                            </td>
                        }
                    </tr>
                }
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
```

Thinking this stuff out and not letting the idea of how it should be done get in the way, can sometimes be my downfall.